# Broadcom BCM4313 takes ages to connect

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm having issues with my broadcom BCM4313 wireless adapter. Everything works just fine when connected (with additional drivers & Connman), but it takes about 5 minutes to connect to my network when i just started my computer! When resuming from hibernation it goes very quick though, so just when I boot my pc it's taking forever...

This is what I found in the dmesg output:

```
[   16.778057] eth1: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 5.60.48.36 
[   16.808768] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient3" pid=833 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.808815] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient3" pid=799 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.808825] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient3" pid=826 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.809367] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=833 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.809415] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=799 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.809435] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=826 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.809705] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=833 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.809755] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=799 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.809769] type=1400 audit(1295859939.727:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=826 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.844083]   alloc irq_desc for 22 on node -1
[   16.844087]   alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
```

Any ideas how come?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you get the driver working?  Is the STA driver, or the B43 firmware from firmware-b43-installer?  Also, is it the low power version?  If you attach the output of `lspci`, the exact models will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I'm using the driver jockey installs, STA I suppose. This is the relevant output of lspci: 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem for the built-in adapter in my laptop. Driver from the `jockey-commons` utility.

Comment: @Scaine, where did you get the package name of drivers?

Comment: I have broadcom 4312 using STA driver which usually takes about 5 seconds to start connecting and a couple more to connect.  I am however now using the interfaces file which gets me connected before desktop appears.   Info can be found here if you don't need to connect to multiple hotspots.  [Using interfaces file for wifi](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7775107&postcount=2)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start a terminal and run

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

Then try connecting to your wifi access point.  You should see the attempts appearing in the terminal window as it tries to connect.

Comment: Well, problem is when I boot my computer, Connman shows no access points. It's only after a minute or 5 that it shows the possibilities... So when it finds the connections, there is no problem connecting, but the searching takes ages!

Comment: Ah okay - the kern.log should be written each boot though, so there might be some useful information in there regarding your chipset.  The /var/log/kern.log is the equivalent of the `dmesg` output.

Comment: Well, I included the relevant dmesg output in my question. Anything comes up to your mind? :)